# Calling a method of a class which is not the viewmodel using CallMethodAction

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

In my application I have a telerik updownbox control which is used inside a telerik grid. I have a viewmodel defined, but I want to call a method of some other class which is not the viewmodel. I am trying to use `CallMethodAction`, but it is looking for a method in the viewmodel. Here is my code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{l:Translate PreloadFv}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding PreLoad,Converter={StaticResource ThreeDecimalConverter}}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Value="{Binding PreLoad}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="UpdateCurve"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </telerik:RadNumericUpDown>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Here I have the `UpdateCurve` method in some other class which is not the viewmodel. I want to call that method on `ValueChanged` event of the `NumericUpDownBox` Control. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Regards
Avik Sen

Comment: As you can see, the way you have pasted your code makes it difficult to read.  In future, please hold the `Alt` key when selecting code in VS to allow you to omit leading spaces and make it easy for us to read.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep this in mind in future.